# javafx mac dmg deploy install location on Applications

Tags: java, macos, javafx, desktop

I builded my javafx application on mac,then i got a dmg file.

but after I installed the application,it created a shortcut on desktop.

What I wanted is a shortcut on Applications like below.

[image: what i wanted]

I tried set a `<fx:bundleArgment arg="systemWide" value="true"/>` in `<fx:deploy>`

but it didn't work.

Is there some parameter that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just spent all day trying to get the answer. Here how to do it with **NetBeans 8.2**

1. In **nbproject** folder find file **project.properties**
2. Open **project.properties** in NetBeans editor
3. Change *javafx.deploy.installpermanently=false* to *javafx.deploy.installpermanently=true*
4. Save **project.properties** file
5. After build DMG file will have link to Applications folder

[image: project.properties]

[image: DMG]